# How to style card in React MUI? Sandbox included

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a card red with MUI. The class is being created, but it's not being applied to the card.

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-solomon-czpsm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you provided `classes={classes.card}` to Card. 
 `classes` expects an object, not a string (you can also see that warning printed to the console):

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid
>   prop `classes` of type `string` supplied to
>   `WithStyles(ForwardRef(Card))`, expected `object`.

Change classes to className, and it will work.

```
<Card className={classes.card}>
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: I don't understand, why does this work then (press the view code icon)? https://material-ui.com/components/cards/#media

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, because in their example i also see className. In short, when you use className you provide a string, only one class name. The styles will apply to the wrapper element. When you use classes, you can directly override all the component styles: https://material-ui.com/api/card/ (go to css section in the bottom). it can look like that: `classes={{root: classes.root, someAnotherRuleKey: classes.someAnotherCss}}`

Answer (score 0):

`className` is equivalent to `class` in HTML.
When you want to pass a class name to a component, you should always use `className` in React.

`classes` on the other hand is an object which you have passed your styles into.

Example usage;

```
<Box className={classes.banner}>Hello World</Box>
```